# PHP.ini file causing WordPress site to crash on Windows IIS

Tags: windows, php, iis, wordpress

I'm running WordPress on Windows IIS (GoDaddy Hosting). The website was created using Visual Composer, which requires an increase in the memory limit. The website is also installed in a subdirectory off the root.

When I create a file named 'php5.ini' file and place it in the subdirectory with the WordPress installation with just:

```
memory_limit = 256M
```

The memory limit is not changed.

When I move the file to the root folder, it doesn't change anything either.

When I add a full php5.ini file with all the declarations, it changes the memory, but then it crashes the site with a 500 internal server error.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I need to set this up in order to get the memory limit to take without crashing the site?

**Update 1/21**

I no longer need this question answered, as my client took GoDaddy's advice and purchased additional hosting on Linux. We moved the website over there, increased the memory and and no issues with it.

I'm leaving the question up while I keep the sample website up to see if anyone can figure out why it wouldn't work. I'm still interested in finding a solution. Thanks!

Comment: I see my question was downvoted. I wish whoever downvoted it would have told me what was wrong with my question instead of just voting it down.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial looks good, what I understand is that you do not have to create a new php5.ini with just that string, rather you should edit your own adding that string.
Plus, there's a trick I did not know.. look [here for this tutorial](http://codingcyber.com/how-to-increase-php-memory-limit-on-godaddy-hosting-882/) hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks NIhvel. We already tried that. (Please see my question as you would have seen we tried that.) Although with our install of being on Windows, we don't "end all". We have to "recycle app pool" in order to get the new changes to register in the INI file.

Comment: so you tried to create the user.ini and add the same string too? Just wondering, are you sure godaddy allows you to increase the amount of memory? some hosting providers can avoid this so users won't take all the available memory
I do not use godaddy to test it, hope you'll find the way

Comment: this is good too! If you missed this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915223/how-to-change-php-memory-limit-at-godaddy/30119230#30119230

Comment: No, because I'm not allowed access to the user.ini file - just allowed to supposedly overwrite the php.ini file. According to GoDaddy (through 4 tech support calls with them), they do allow you increase the amount of memory. And as I mentioned in the post above, we can successfully increase the memory, but it crashes the site.

Comment: And actually, I did just try adding the user.ini file, but that didn't help either. :/ Thank you for trying to help. I appreciate it.